# call jQuery does not return the right data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to get a string back into a jQuery call, but nothing is passed

code of function in php File

```php
function setTableData()
{
    $handle = fopen("/tmp/setTableData.log", "w");
    $data='[{id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5}]';
    echo($data);
    fclose($handle);    //chiusura file 
}
```

code in js

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "modules/Customers/CustomersAjax.php",           
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  datatype:'json',
  data: "action=setTableData", 
  success: function (esito2) {    
    alert(esito2);
  }
});
```

the alert I put prints empty

Comment: is the function `setTableData` getting called at all?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function file opening method.

```
$handle = fopen("/tmp/setTableData.log", "w");
$data='[{id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5}]';
echo($data);
fclose($handle);    //chiusura file
```

Please don't write your code in a function, write your code directly in php file, It works perfectly then.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: it doesn't work.. i think the problem is jquery call

Comment: Please don't write your code in a function, write your code directly in php file, It works perfectly then.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
// Add your return data to this array
$data = array(
    "id" => 1, "name" => "oli",
);


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```